# I want my disabled text will be the placeholder for my select box

Tags: html, select, input

I want my "-- Please Select --" should be like the placeholder for my select box. But when I put *disabled* the output of my select box placeholder appears "1", any idea? 
      here's my code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
         <select>
           <option value="" disabled>--- Please Select ---</option>
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
         </select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put in `selected` too. It will auto-select the first non-disabled item.

```
<option value="" disabled selected>--- Please Select ---</option>
```

And the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wvdca3d1/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this HTML:

```
    <option value=‟--Please Select--" disabled>select</option>
```

Comment: OP wants it to be `disabled`. Removing the `disabled` isn't a fix.